# How do i pass incoming data(NDJ) from an API to another API in CSV format without creating a file?

Tags: node.js

I have an API to which I am getting a response in NDJ format as shown below and want to pass the response as a csv(comma separated values) to another API

```
{"country":"Germany","os":"Windows 7","utm_campaign":"(none)","utm_medium":"direct / organic","from_mobile":false,"base_browser":"Chrome","utm_term":"(none)","domain":"furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com","browser":"Chrome 76.0.3809","repeat":true,"location":"Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany","base_os":"Windows","utm_source":"(none)"}{"country":"Germany","os":"Windows 7","utm_campaign":"(none)","utm_medium":"direct / organic","from_mobile":false,"base_browser":"Chrome","utm_term":"(none)","domain":"furnitureshop4u-2.myshopify.com","browser":"Chrome 76.0.3809","repeat":true,"location":"Meinerzhagen - North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany","base_os":"Windows","utm_source":"(none)"}
```

I tried to buffer the response from the source API and changed it using memorystream and converted to csv(comma separated values). Now I am struck here I dont know how to transfer the data to the destination API.

```
var body = {"request_json" :JSON.stringify(options)};
    var apicall = {
        url: API,
        method: 'post',
        responseType: 'stream',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: body
    }
    axios(apicall).then((res) =>{
       var writer = new MemoryStream(null, {
           readable : true
       }) // using memorystream to stream the buffer
       res.data.pipe(writer); // writing data to a writer
       writer.on('data',function(dat){
           console.log(dat); //getting buffer
           var e = dat.toString();
           console.log(e);
           var x = JSON.parse(e);
           var y = [x];
           console.log(y); // converted to JSON
           var keys = Object.keys(x);
           var csv = json2csv.convertArrayOfObjects(y, keys) //converting to csv comma separated string
           console.log(csv,'Final');
       });       
       writer.on('end', function(){
        //console.log('updated ---- ',data);
       });

    }).catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e);
    })
```

I want to just pipe the data from source API to destination API in a CSV format without storing the data into a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are already converting incoming data to stream using memorystream then we can convert it and stream directly to destination API as below

```
const axios = require('axios')
const FormData = require('form-data')
const MemoryStream = require('memorystream')
const { AsyncParser } = require('json2csv')

const body = { request_json: JSON.stringify(options) }
const apicall = {
    url: API,
    method: 'post',
    responseType: 'stream',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: body
}
axios(apicall)
.then(res => {
    var writer = new MemoryStream(null, {
        readable: true
    })
    const transformOpts = { encoding: 'utf-8' }
    const asyncParser = new AsyncParser(transformOpts)
    asyncParser.fromInput(res.data).toOutput(writer)
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('source', 'sample_table')
    formData.append('file', writer, {filename:file,contentType:'text/csv'})
    axios
        .post(finalAPI, formData, {
            headers: formData.getHeaders(),
            maxContentLength: 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
        })
        .then(function(a) {
            console.log('SUCCESS!!', a)
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log('FAILURE!!', e)
        })
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```